# New Relic not dispatching NRQL alert condition for process when errors are triggered

Tags: aws-lambda, newrelic, nrql

I'm creating a monitoring for a process using New Relic. The process itself is an AWS Lambda that finishes running in around 15 seconds. Any time this process fails, I want to an alert to be triggered and an email to be sent to me per the policy I've configured.

For testing purposes I'm causing the lambda to fail in a QA environment multiple times in a row to see what gets picked up by New Relic, although in production the failure would only occur a couple (less than 3) times per week, potentially a few days apart.

Here is the chart that depicts all of the failures, the NRQL query, and the thresholds. As we can see, the summed errors are well above the threshold but for some reason the alert email is not being dispatched. Any ideas? [image]

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing your evaluation offset in `Condition Settings -> Advanced Settings > Evaluation offset`

New Relic polls for Lambda metrics [every 5 minutes](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/integrations/amazon-integrations/get-started/polling-intervals-aws-integrations) so if your offset is lower than this you may find that the alert doesn't fire.

In reality I've found this quite unreliable and I'd suggest setting quite a high offset initially to test the alert - maybe 20 or 30 minutes.

Answer (score -1):

According to me the red highlighted area is the timeframe where the alert condition is being violated. Alert should had been triggered, check your notification channel and try sending test notification.